# Type of expression is ambigious without more context Error

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I want a `Array` with a `struct`. When I fill the array it says: **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

```
static func getSubmenuItems() -> [CellData] {
    var arrCellData = [CellData]()
    arrCellData = [CellData(cell: 1, text: "Börse", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_boerse")),
                   CellData(cell: 2, text: "Börsengeschichte", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_boerse")),
                   CellData(cell: 3, text: "Weltmarkt", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_boerse")),
                   CellData(cell: 4, text: "Quiz", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_boerse")),]
    return arrCellData
}
```

The struct is in another file. Anybody got a idea?

```
struct CellData {
   let cell: Int!
   let text: String!
   let image: UIImage!
}
```

Comment: In which line the error occurs? Please provide more details.

Comment: in line 5: arrCellData = [cellData (cell: 1, ....

Comment: Why are you creating a `[cellData]` in the `var` line and then immediately throwing it away in the next line? There is no need for `arrCellData` here and it's forcing an unnecessary allocation. (Note that in Swift, type names have a leading capital, so this should be `[CellData]`). Why have you put `!` on all the types in the struct? This may be causing your problem.

Comment: Trying your updated code, this still doesn't reproduce (the `!` are poor Swift, but they're not causing the problem). You'll need to find a small example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You also have a typo in your code, there's an extra comma after the last element of the array.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani thanks a lot it helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is work if I used:**

`UIImage(named:"icon_boerse")` instead of `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_boerse")`